# Deleting an entity from a table which is dependent on another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables MachineGroups and Machines. MachineGroups has columns:

- MachinegroupID
- MachineGroupName
- MachineGroupDesc

And Machines has columns:

- MachineGroupID (FK)
- MachineID
- MachineName
- Machinedesc

Now I want to delete a machinegroup but not the ones that have machines in it.
So if there are machines it should give an error message.... saying you cannot delete.

Here is what I am trying to do.....

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="2"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
     Width="100%" ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound1"
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound1">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#D0D8E8" ForeColor="#333333" Height="35px" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MachineGroupID" HeaderText="MachineGroupID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MachineGroupID" 
            Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MachineGroupName" HeaderText="MachineGroupName" 
            SortExpression="MachineGroupName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MachineGroupDesc" HeaderText="MachineGroupDesc" 
            SortExpression="MachineGroupDesc" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeAdded" HeaderText="TimeAdded" 
            SortExpression="TimeAdded" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CanBeDeleted" SortExpression="CanBeDeleted" 
            Visible="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"
                    Checked='<%# Bind("CanBeDeleted") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"
                    Checked='<%# Bind("CanBeDeleted") %>' Enabled="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="No. of PCs" HeaderText="No. of PCs" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="No. of PCs" />
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                    CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4F81BD" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"
        Height="30px" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E9EDF4" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:GridView>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SumooHAgentDBConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName, MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, MachineGroups.TimeAdded, MachineGroups.CanBeDeleted, COUNT(Machines.MachineName) AS 'No. of PCs' FROM MachineGroups FULL OUTER JOIN Machines ON Machines.MachineGroupID = MachineGroups.MachineGroupID GROUP BY MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName, MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, MachineGroups.TimeAdded, MachineGroups.CanBeDeleted" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM MachineGroups WHERE (MachineGroupID = @original_MachineGroupID) AND (MachineGroupName = @original_MachineGroupName) AND (MachineGroupDesc = @original_MachineGroupDesc) AND (CanBeDeleted = @original_CanBeDeleted) AND (TimeAdded = @original_TimeAdded)">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_MachineGroupID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_MachineGroupName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_MachineGroupDesc" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CanBeDeleted" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TimeAdded" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Please suggest what to do..

Comment: This is not a difficult question for SQL, or for SQL with C#.  However, requiring us to also be expert at ASP.Net may be narrowing your potential helpers down quite a bit.  If you could phase this question so that we did not have to tease the SQL out of the XML/HTML (or whatever this is) apply the SQL solution and then figure out how to reapply it to your ASP.net again, you might get more/better answers.

Comment: Opps, that's "phrase" not "phase".

Comment: @RBarryYoung, seeing as the OP is using a SqlDataSource, solutions to his problem that don't involve surplus code are very ASP.NET specific.

Answer (score 1):

Handle your GridView's **RowDeleting** and **RowDeleted** events.  In `RowDeleting`, you can run the query suggested by Palo, and run a query to check if the group is empty:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int mgid = e.Keys["MachineGroupId"];
    if (!GroupIsEmpty(mgid))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

In 'RowDeleted', you can check if there was an exception, as there should be when your constraints are working properly, and you don't cancel the delete as described above:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Exception != null) && (e.ExceptionHandled))
    {
        errorLabel.Text = "Machine group could not be deleted.  This is probably because machines still exist for the group.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the child rows first. So maybe have 2 delete procedures.  Something like:

```
DELETE 
FROM machines 
WHERE
MachineGroupID = @IN_MachineGroupID

DELETE 
FROM machinesGroups 
WHERE
MachineGroupID = @IN_MachineGroupID
```

Using DataSets, and DataAdapters make this easier in my opinion. Look into ADO.Net disconnected layer.

I noticed you want to throw an error - Do you have code behind page?

You need to do

```
Try
{
   call your delete;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   throw (ex.Messgae)
}
```

you can be more exact on the error you looking for but you get the idea.

Comment: I dont need to delete the child row...
I just need to display an error message in a label...
so is there a way to delete the rows which dont have any machines and show error for the ones that have machines...

Answer (score 0):

In good old SQL, all you need to do is delete the entries in MachineGroups that are not listed as a MachineGroupID in the Machines table:

```
DELETE FROM MachineGroups
 WHERE MachineGroupID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MachineGroupID FROM Machines)
```

How you convert that into ASP/XML is anyone's guess.

Comment: I don't think he wants to delete all machine groups that don't have any machines.  He wants to handle the delete button press for a specific machine group and throw an error if that machine group still has any machines left in it.

Comment: @Mark: so he needs to add 'AND MachineGroupID = 123456'.  That will delete group 123456 unless it still has entries.  He'd have to analyze the number of rows deleted to know whether the row was removed; deleting zero rows is not a failure.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a foreign key relationship between the two tables `Machines` and `MachineGroups`, right? (based on the MachineGroupID)

If that FK relationship does not specify the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, then what you can do is

- try to delete the machine group
- catch any exception that might happen that indicates it cannot be deleted because of existing child rows
- display that message (or a more user-friendly "translation" thereof) to the user

If that FK relationship however does specify the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, then you'd have to first check to make sure there are not child rows for a given `MachineGroupID` before deleting that machine group.

Marc

Comment: what u just said is right... but i dont have a on delete cascade option.. so ill have to use the second option...
can u help me with that..

Answer (score 0):

Run a simple count on machines with that group id:

```
select count(id) from Machines where MachineGroupId == groupIdToDelete;
```

If there is a count you can display a nice error message or whatever.

If there is no count, proceed with the removal.